# How to create two udp sockets where one is sending requests and another one receiving the answers?

Tags: go, udp, client-server

I'm looking for a proper way to have one goroutine sending out request packets to specific  servers while a second goroutine receiving the responses and handling them, maybe even create a new goroutine for each response to handle.

The architecture of the game is that there are multiple masterservers, which can be asked for ip lists of registered servers.
After getting the ips and ports from the masterservers, each of the ips gets a request for its data, like server name, map, players, etc.

Also, are there better ways to handle this?
Currently I am creating a goroutine per request that also waits for a response afterwards.
The waiting for a response timeouts after 35ms and continues to send 1.2 times the previous amount of request packets  to have a small burst of requests. Also the timeout is doubled on every retry.

I'd like to know if there are better strategies that have proven to be more robust and have a lower latency, that are not too complex.

Edit:
I only create the client side sockets, but would have, if there is no better approach, a client that sends UDP request packets that contain a different socket's address as sender value in order to receive the answers on a different socket that acts kind of like a server, where all the response packets are collected. In order to separate the sending socket from the receiving socket.

This question is tagged as client-server as one of the sockets is supposed to act like a server, even tho all it does is receive expected answers in response to request packets sent by the client socket.

Comment: Well... There is a pattern for request and responses already. UDP for such data is a Very Bad Idea™, as UDP packages have no transport guarantee — any active network device, including the receiving server may choose to silently discard those packages. To me, it sounds like you are reinventing the wheel. Personally, I have used [HashiCorp‘s memberlist](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/memberlist?tab=doc) for cluster membership management and [GRPC](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc?tab=doc) to methods and share information.

Comment: I do not have control over the protocol, all I do is collect server data.

Comment: Wait, you can create sockets, but you can not control the protocol? Well... a simple google search answers that https://ops.tips/blog/udp-client-and-server-in-go/

Comment: I only create the client side sockets, but would have, if there is no better approach, a client that sends UDP request packets that contain a different socket's address as sender value in order to receive the answers on a different socket that acts kind of like a server, where all the response packets are collected. In order to separate the sending socket from the receiving socket.

Comment: TBH, you lost me. I would argue that this is a bad sign. Again, UDP is not suitable for what you want. Unless you are very careful and do packet accounting, it is very likely that at one point or the other, you miss crucial packages. You basically will have to write an own implementation of TCP _and_ create both a cluster membership protocol and some sort of RPC on top of that to do what you want. Sorry for the French, but that is a metric shitload of code to end up with what is basically TCP and protocols already implemented on top of that.